# Difference between Laravel DB::insert() and DB::table()->insert()

Tags: database, laravel, insert

I've been trying to figure out which one to use when, and if I should even use both.

Been looking at Laravel docs and they have both in there. From what I can make out of it, `DB::insert()` provides more "tailored" query than `DB::table()->insert()` does.

Would anyone be able to clarify what exactly the difference is in the two when it comes to how and when to use which?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

- `DB::insert()` for  [raw sql queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries). Example:

  `DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', [1, 'Dayle']);`
- `DB::table()->insert()` for [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#inserts). Example:

  `DB::table('users')->insert(
      ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
  );`

Query builder compiles conditions to raw sql query, but I am using it because it is much more convenient.

Comment: That's what I figured it was. But is any prefered compared to the other? For example, I didn't know how to use "insert ignore" with Query Builder, so I chose raw sql.

So are there any pros and cons to consider when using either of them?

Comment: You've answered your question. Query builder is for most common cases, if you need some specific - use raw query. There ar no pros and cons, they do same thing in different ways. Query builder is more convinient and readable - that's all.

Comment: Hi, after running a DB::insert() the next PDO prepared statement complains with the following error:

> [2017-06-08 03:04:41] local.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

Is there a command that needs to be run after every DB::insert() ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You always try to use query builder as much as possible, it prevents SQL injection.

*The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings*

Query Builder also helps with special chars such as ', " in values. For raw statement, you need to take care of the special chars yourself.

Answer (score -2):

public function addsubEmployee(Request $reqest){

```
    Sub_employee::create([
        "se_name"=> $reqest->se_name,
    ]);

    return redirect()->route("subEmployee");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).